# How to update Github repo

Tags: github

If I have a github repository that I succesfully pushed code to from my local machine, how do I commit further update? I've tried `git push origin master` and this returns by saying "Everything Up to Date", when I know that I'm making changes to the files that are not being sent to github at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit your new changes first.

```
git commit -a -m "Your message here"
```

Comment: Hey actually I don't know what happened but this worked. I've heard though that -a is not best practice and can be "dangerous". Is this at all true?

Comment: -a adds files to commit automatically, meaning that you can accidentally commit changes you don't mean to. If you want to be safe, do git add and git commit in separate steps, and use git status to make sure you're committing the right files.